# Counting occurences by month in a timestamp field in Presto

Tags: sql, presto

I have a field that is timestamp type and I want to count records per month, like this:

```
Date
2021-01-23
2021-01-12
2021-03-12
```

Should return

```
Jan Mar
2    1
```

How can I do this in prestodb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your data pivoted you can do:

```
-- sample data
WITH dataset (date) AS (
    VALUES (date '2021-01-23'),
        (date '2021-01-12'),
        (date '2021-03-12')
) 

--query
select count_if(month(date) = 1) as Jan,
    count_if(month(date) = 2) as Feb,
    count_if(month(date) = 3) as Mar 
    -- ...
from dataset
```

Output:

| Jan | Feb | March |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 0 | 1 |

For "regular" columnar format just use grouping by formatted short month name:

```
--query
select date_format(date, '%b') month, count(*) count
from dataset
group by date_format(date, '%b')
```

Output:

| month | count |
| --- | --- |
| Mar | 1 |
| Jan | 2 |

Comment: thanks!  How to can to adapt to count months by years?  because I can have 2021-January and 2022 January

Comment: @Katty_one first approach is not very scalable and second one - add the year to the grouping and result, for example modifying format string (see formats [here](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#mysql-date-functions))